# change a json array into a 2d array

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

So i have a Json file like this:

```
{"matches_details": [{"MatchID": "Liverpool-Manchester United", "Date": "17/12/2020", "Time": "16:00", "Score": "5-0", "Yellow cards": "2", "Red cards": "1", "State": "FT"}, {"MatchID": "Crystal Palace-Chelsea", "Date": "20/1/2021", "Time": "11:00", "Score": "10-0", "Yellow cards": "10", "Red cards": "20", "State": "HT"}]}
```

The way to print out all the array is:

```
f = open('datngu.json',)
    data = json.load(f)
    for i in data['matches_details']:
        print(i)

    f.close()
```

And the way to print a single one:

```
print(data['matches_details']['MatchID'])
```

So how can i change it into a 2d array with row,col format, because i need to insert these data into a pyqt5 qtTableWidgetItem UI

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48687857/python-json-list-to-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following if you would like to have it as a pd.DataFrame():

```py
import pandas as pd

values = {"matches_details": [{"MatchID": "Liverpool-Manchester United", "Date": "17/12/2020", "Time": "16:00", "Score": "5-0", "Yellow cards": "2", "Red cards": "1", "State": "FT"}, {"MatchID": "Crystal Palace-Chelsea", "Date": "20/1/2021", "Time": "11:00", "Score": "10-0", "Yellow cards": "10", "Red cards": "20", "State": "HT"}]}

df_table = pd.DataFrame(values['matches_details'])
```

If you prefer it as a numpy 2D-array, just do the following:

```
arr_2d = df_table.values
```

Comment: so what is the 1st follwing about

Comment: The first part helps you to put the json in a DataFrame format (a table).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use numpy as follows:

```
m = np.zeros((len(match_details_json), 7))
for i, elem in enumerate(match_details_json):
    m[i,0] = elem['MatchID']
    m[i,1] = elem['Date']
    m[i,2] = elem['Time']
    m[i,3] = elem['Score']
    m[i,4] = elem['Yellow cards']
    m[i,5] = elem['Red cards']
    m[i,5] = elem['State']
```

Comment: what is 'match_details_json'?

Comment: This will be the json string that you want to convert to array