# Converting Json to pd

Tags: arrays, json, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm trying to convert the Json type data to dataframe. I extrated data from following webpage with following code.

[webpage I extract data](https://www.hkex.com.hk/Mutual-Market/Stock-Connect/Statistics/Historical-Monthly?sc_lang=en#select1=0&select2=0)

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

url = r'https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/csm/MonthlyStat/data_tab_monthly_202302e.js?_=1'

response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code != 200:
    exit(1)

text = response.text[response.text.index('=') + 1:]
data = json.loads(text)
```

However, I come across some problem when I trying to conver the Json to dataframe.
I have tried using following code, but the result seem didn't change when I change the max_level.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data, max_level=2)
```

It seems different from the JSON I met before. Too many data in one json, I only need style 1 data from all id. I am unsure if I using the right code. I'm the beginner in Json. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Json List to Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48687857/python-json-list-to-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

url = r'https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/csm/MonthlyStat/data_tab_monthly_202302e.js?_=1'

response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code != 200:
    exit(1)

text = response.text[response.text.index('=') + 1:]
data = json.loads(text)
```

Here your data is of type `dict` as the `json.loads` function converts json to the python native datatype.

`json.normalize` will normalize your `dict` value if there is nesting in it. In your case it is stopping at a point where there is a list value for a key.

In this api response, the content value is a list which cannot be normalized as it is a list.

You can read more about this [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html).

Comment: So, do you know which method should I use?

Comment: depends on how you want your dataframe? can you share the columns that you want to see considering the data in the response.

Comment: Sure! The first table format shown on the webpage is exactly what I want, Which means the columns are 'Feb 2023', 'Jan 2023', '%Change', and that is 'style: 1' content in JSON format. 

But, I want all 'style: 1' content from id: 0 - id:3, these are:
'Shanghai Connect Northbound(SSE Northbound)', 
'Shanghai Connect Southbound(SSE Southbound)', 
'Shenzhen Connect Northbound(SZSE Northbound)', 
'Shenzhen Connect Southbound(SEZE Southbound)'. 

In other words, I want four tables from this JSON, which can be selected from the upper right box.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found what I want is to extract the data from JSON. And I finally found the method to take the data from JSON. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

url = r'https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/csm/MonthlyStat/data_tab_monthly_202302e.js?_=1'

response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code != 200:
    exit(1)

text = response.text[response.text.index('=') + 1:]
data = json.loads(text)

df = pd.json_normalize(data, max_level=2)
length = len(data[0]['content'][0]['table']['tr'][1:])
SSENorthbound_df = pd.DataFrame([data[0]['content'][0]['table']['tr'][1:][x].get('td')[0] for x in range(length)])

df = pd.json_normalize(data, max_level=2)
length = len(data[1]['content'][0]['table']['tr'][1:])
SSESouthbound_df = pd.DataFrame([data[1]['content'][0]['table']['tr'][1:][x].get('td')[0] for x in range(length)])

df = pd.json_normalize(data, max_level=2)
length = len(data[2]['content'][0]['table']['tr'][1:])
SZSENorthbound_df = pd.DataFrame([data[2]['content'][0]['table']['tr'][1:][x].get('td')[0] for x in range(length)])

df = pd.json_normalize(data, max_level=2)
length = len(data[3]['content'][0]['table']['tr'][1:])
SZSE_Southbound_df = pd.DataFrame([data[3]['content'][0]['table']['tr'][1:][x].get('td')[0] for x in range(length)])
```